# Скачивание файла происходит в фоновом режиме react ts

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, файлы, typescript

У меня есть приложение, которое загружает разные типы файлов. Он работает регулярно, но при нажатии
на скачивания оно выполняется в фоновом режиме, и браузер показывает скачивания файла только тогда, когда весь поток был загружен локально. Таким образом, если скачивания файла занимает 1 минуту, пользователь не понимает, что делает сайт. Есть ли способ показать индикатор выполнения скачивания как в google? (есть ли возможность сделать так же как на скрине) [image: индикатор скачивания]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Не виден прогресс скачивания.